# Problema para obter valor do input com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou pegando o valor do `input` através de JS e enviando via `GET` para outra página. O problema, é que quando digito espaço dentro o `input`, não consigo pegar o que escrevi depois do espaço.

Se eu digitar por exemplo: **Ana Maria** o JS só pega o **Ana.**

O HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="nome" onkeyup="pegaNome()">
<div id="aqui"></div>
```

A função JS:

```
 function pegaNome(){

    var campo=document.getElementById('nome').value;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aqui').append(campo);

});
```

Comment: Retire  `$(document).ready(function(){` e acrescente `$('#aqui').html('');` antes do append. Você não está usando $(document).ready(function(){ da maneira correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
function pegaNome(valor) {
  document.getElementById("aqui").innerHTML = valor;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nome" onkeyup="pegaNome(this.value);">
<div id="aqui"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sugestão ou faça em *Javascript* puro ou *JQuery*, fica mais fácil para entender a lógica. (No seu exemplo havia mistura de JQuery com Javascript puro)

**Segue abaixo o seu exemplo funcionando em Jquery.**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nome").keypress(function(){
        var valor = $("#nome").val();
        $("#aqui").text(valor);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="nome">
<div id="aqui"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Em javascript puro:**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function peganome(valor) {
      document.getElementById("aqui").innerHTML = valor;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="nome" onkeyup="peganome(this.value);">
    <div id="aqui"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Em AngularJS** (sem jquery ou qualquer outro plugin)

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="nome">
      <hr>
      <h1>Olá {{nome}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> OBS: Em AngularJS é o mais fácil basicamente é um ng-model="nome" e
>   depois para exibir é {{nome}}, porém utilizar o AngularJS somente para
>   isso é como ter uma Ferrari para ir apenas na padaria.